# Геопозицирование парсера (php)

Tags: php, парсер

Может звучит бредово,но нужно. Хотел сделать парсер который читает данные предприятий по определенному тегу на сайте. Но тут вышла одна беда, сайт использует поиск местонахождения. Когда я начинаю парсить данные в ответе приходит, что местоположение не определенно. Не знаю как быть. Как подсунуть сайту координаты если даже бвить их руками

Comment: посмотрите что делает сайт при указании местоположения. Там что-то будет либо записываться в куки,  либо отправляться запрос и сохранение в сессию, как вариант - редирект, и т.п.. В любом случае данные действия потребуется повторить программно. так что ф12 и инструменты браузера вам в помощь.

Comment: если приходит такой ответ, то как минимум IP - geoIP не при делах. значит заголовки - язык системы/браузера..

Comment: Я смотрел в консоль там самое интересное это куки, но куки ему подкидываю через cUrl и нет результата, там есть и координаты и адрес мол, но безисходно. Так понимаю что у куков есть ид и по нему он отслеживает какие куки пришли это значение постоянно меняется.